# Can one formulate a fluctuation-dissipation theorem in presence of non-Gaussian noise sources?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, noise, fluctuation-dissipation

The [fluctuation dissipation theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation-dissipation_theorem) relates the linear response of a system to Gaussian fluctuations. The natural question that comes to my mind is the possible derivation of an analogous FDT in presence of non-Gaussian noise. I would like to know if such an attempt has already been made with links to relevant literature. If not, then what are the difficulties (conceptual or technical) towards such a derivation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in the nonlinear fluctuation dissipation theorem. Here are some sources:

1) [A review by Lucarini and Colangeli](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.1073)

2) [The classic book by Stratonovich on nonlinear fluctuations (very advanced)](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642773457)

3) [One of the original papers by Efremov](http://jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/dn/e_028_06_1232.pdf)

4) [Application of the nonlinear FDT to classical plasmas](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01023681)

5) [A more readable paper (with references) on the application of nonlinear FDT to plasmas that I wrote a few years ago](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.4889)

6) [Kubo's second book on statistical physics (might be one of the best sources if you can get a copy)](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540538332)

EDIT: Here are some possibly more relevant references for you on a linear system driven by non-Gaussian noise:

[A paper by Kanazawa et. al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2233)

[A presentation by Kanazawa](http://www2.yukawa.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~ykis2015.ws/Presentation/Kanazawa.pdf)

[A paper by Dubkov et. al.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9ae9/13e58936b16db526f80380249983d8a33c24.pdf)

[A paper by Field et. al.](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1142933)

[A proof by Grafov](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1025736323804)

Comment: Thanks for the references. I will take a look at them. I do have the Kubo's two volume book and it's a great reference. I just wanted some clarification on FDTs for linear Langevin systems driven by non-Gaussian noise. Would appreciate any comments on that. I am not explicitly asking about non-linearity in responses here.

Comment: @noisyoscillator Added a few additional references that might be more what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joshuah. These latest additions are more in line with what I was looking for. I was going through Kanazawa's work and his Springer thesis while you posted the links. I appreciate your help in this regard. Cheers and a happy new year!

Comment: Still it looks like a general FDR for linear systems driven by non-Gaussian sources is missing. I found a paper discussing an FDR when the system is driven by Lévy type noise.